# 2 inner joins to same data on other table

Tags: mysql, sql

im a bit stuck in my understanding of this

I have 2 tables ...'games' and 'teams'

```
**teams**

teamID,teamName
1, Bears
2, Steelers
3, Giants
4, Bengals
...


**Games**

gameID,awayTeamID,homeTeamID
10, 1,2
20, 3,4
```

Im trying to write a query where I will return the games, but bring back the teamNames of both the home and away team also (or even 'instead', as I dont actually need the IDs in the final query)

I tried an INNER JOIN, and if I link .. 'games.homeTeamID=teams.teamID' then it will successfully bring back teamID into my query ...However, i need to do the same with 'awayTeamID'  so i tried 2 INNER JOINS

```
SELECT * FROM games INNER JOIN teams on games.awayTeamID=teams.teamID  INNER JOIN teams on games.homeTeamID=teams.teamID
```

But naturally I get an SQL error as im trying to join to same item twice

**#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'teams**

.. I want my query result to look like this

```
gameID,awayTeamID,homeTeamID,awayTeamNAME,homeTeamNAME,
10, 1,2,Bears, Steelers
20, 3,4,Giants,Bengals
```

or

```
gameID,awayTeamNAME,homeTeamNAME,
10,Bears, Steelers
20,Giants,Bengals
```

...of course **awayTeamNAME** and **homeTeamNAME** dont exist yet though so this is a problem :-)

Apologies if this is a really simple issue, but does anyone know how I can reference the same item in the teams table for 2 different result objects?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an alias on table names :

```
SELECT *
FROM games
INNER JOIN teams -- ----------------+
on games.awayTeamID=teams.teamID -- +------ Same table name, you can't tell how the join is applied
INNER JOIN teams -- ----------------+
on games.homeTeamID=teams.teamID
```

Change your query to this (notice the join condition too, games.awayTeamID=**T1**.teamID and games.homeTeamID=**T2**.teamID) :

```
SELECT T1.teamName AS AwayTeam,
       T2.teamName AS HomeTeam
FROM games
INNER JOIN teams T1 -- ----------------+
on games.awayTeamID=T1.teamID --       +------ Tables are now aliased
INNER JOIN teams T2 -- ----------------+
on games.homeTeamID=T2.teamID
```

Comment: @gbt Their query does change the column headers of the results.

Comment: Hi Cid ..yep, my mistake, all working perfectly  - marked as the Answer ....thanks so much again

Answer (score 4):

A couple of table aliases should fix your issue.

```
SELECT * 
FROM games 
INNER JOIN teams AS awayTeam
  on games.awayTeamID=awayTeam.teamID  
INNER JOIN teams AS homeTeam
  on games.homeTeamID=homeTeam.teamID
```

Comment: Thanks Eric ...thanks, it does brings back the names ...However , is there anyway to change the column headers ?  it returns 'teamName' as the column header for both returned items .. Im going to be passing this into a Jinja2 template where I reference the values specifically by th column header name e.g  {{myQueryReturn.teamName}}  ... if both of them are the same then it wont know which one to reference  ..is this possible do you know ?

Comment: @gbt, then you just need column aliases in your `SELECT` list, e.g. `teamName AS homeTeamName`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  games, teams
where
  games.awayTeamID = teams.teamID
  or games.homeTeamID = teams.teamID
```

[MySQL 8.0 Reference JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

I hope that is your help

Comment: What in the world? You can't include a table in your WHERE clause that you haven't JOINed to. And your WHERE clause, even if there were a join to `teams` would require that both the `awayTeamID` and the `homeTeamID` be the same `teams.teamID`, which is unlikely at best. I'm not down-voting, but you should consider taking this answer down as it is incorrect.

Comment: Fix. Now make a inner join.

Comment: Please do **never** post w3schools links as reference, that's a **terrible** reference. There is plenty of errors in that site, that has no affiliation with W3C. Rather, give official documentation (MySQL documentation is pretty nice)